# Paid Membership Pro memberlist csv export

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I have been asked to make a small change in the members list export in csv format on a wordpress site that uses the Paid Memberships Pro plug-in.

By default, export features prices in the format 120.00000000 and 63.50000000, and my client needs it in french format : 120,00 and 63,50 .

But the plugin setting doesn't offer such option.

I am planing to add a couple of lines of php with "number_format" right after the csv content is generated.

The "export in csv" function uses the following url : "domain/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=memberslist_csv" . But I am not familiar with WordPress, and after checking the admin-ajax.php file, I am stuck.

Furthermore, I have the feeling that the plugin overrides the core WP ajax calls.

Where should I look to find the generated csv content to be able to modify it ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the file to modify :

.../wp-content/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/adminpages/memberslist-csv.php